# How to include one js script in all views except the landing page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am converting css template into MVC application. Needless to say, I am just a beginner into webdesign. Template contains reference to one js script, which needs to be included on all pages except the landing page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider_func_innerpage.js"></script>
```

How to achieve it in MVC without creation of another master page? I tried to put this line in all views except of default view, but nothing happened. Ideally, I would like to handle this in my _Layout.cshtml file. Is it possible to set there some "if" condition, which would, if true, call partial view containing that single line I posted above? Or is there a more elegant way to load that js file into all views with the exception of the default one?

Comment: Using two different layout pages is the way to do it

Comment: Probably yes, I just dont like the idea of having two identical layouts where the difference is in only one line, so I am trying some workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not prefer to create another layout for landing page (*Why not ? This seems to be the right way of doing it*) , you might consider conditionally loading this js file in your layout.

So in the view for landing page, set a flag to the ViewBag dictionary

```
@{
  ViewBag.IsLandingPage = true;
}
```

Now in the layout, check this flag and if it is not null and true, Exclude the inclusion of your js file

```
@{
    if (ViewBag.IsLandingPage == null)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider_func_innerpage.js"></script>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Two master layouts seemed to me as a too much work because of one extra row. Also, as I learned later, this js file was changing only a simple paramer (height of one DIV). I will try to change that parameter in Jquery but for now, this works good, too

Comment: Done. Changed it in Jquery, looks cleaner to me. Still, had to use ViewBag.IsLandingPage as you suggested. Thanks again.